# I have implemented a simple ANN but not getting the desired output

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, prediction, training-data

Is there something wrong with the code or do I need to include more input data records and change the number of hidden layers ? I am referring this [tutorial](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5H_HYFhs40naHVqMng2REZkbTA/view) (Pg 4)

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

ann = cv2.ml.ANN_MLP_create()
ann.setTrainMethod(cv2.ml.ANN_MLP_RPROP | cv2.ml.ANN_MLP_UPDATE_WEIGHTS)
ann.setActivationFunction(cv2.ml.ANN_MLP_SIGMOID_SYM)
ann.setLayerSizes(np.array([10, 9, 3]))
ann.setTermCriteria(( cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS | cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_COUNT, 10, 1 ))

i1 = [190, 150, 170, 290, 280, 270, 400, 320, 330,349]
i2 = [95, 95, 31, 64, 98, 39, 18, 12, 48,74]
i3 = [48, 45, 19, 78, 23, 32, 30, 32, 33,79]

o1 = [0, 0, 1]
o2 = [0, 1, 0]
o3 = [1, 0, 0]

SAMPLES = 5000  
for x in range(0, SAMPLES):
  print "Samples %d/%d" % (x, SAMPLES)
  ann.train(np.array([i1,i2,i3], dtype=np.float32), cv2.ml.ROW_SAMPLE, np.array([o1,o2,o3], dtype=np.float32))  

print ann.predict(np.array([i1], dtype=np.float32))
print ann.predict(np.array([i2], dtype=np.float32)) 
print ann.predict(np.array([i3], dtype=np.float32))
```

I am getting my output as

```
(0.0, array([[nan,         nan,         nan]], dtype=float32))
(0.0, array([[nan,         nan,         nan]], dtype=float32))
(0.0, array([[nan,         nan,         nan]], dtype=float32))
```

Shouldn't the expected output be

```
(0.0, .......
(1.0, .......
(2.0, .......
```

Why am I getting 'nan' ?

Is there any other way to predict output for data that ANN hasn't seen ?
    Example - [84, 43, 89, 74, 45, 32, 78, 46, 43, 45]

Comment: Does train method normalized data? ANN is universal function aproximator, so if you perform "good" trainning ANN will be able make prediction on unseened data.

Comment: I haven't normalized the data yet. I am predict output for the data ANN has already seen. That should give the correct output regardless.

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem in my ANN libralies when I set too hight lerning speed parametr. Weights start oslilating (1,-1.5,2,-2.5  0-"good weight") and fast go out from range of variables. Bigger networks should have smaller lerning speed parametr.